# Changing font and background color of jTableHeader

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to change the background color and font size of jTableHeader but it only changes the background color. Heres the code:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRenderer.setBackground(new Color(239,198,46));
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    centerRenderer.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(centerRenderer);
```

I don't understand why it only changes the background.
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `table.getTableHeader().setBackground()` and `table.getTableHeader().setFont()` directly instead of trying to change the header renderer. Try this example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TableHeaderFont
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JTable table = new JTable(new String[][] {{"11", "22"}, {"33", "44"}}, new String[] {"ABC", "DEF"});
    table.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(239,198,46));
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: it works fine if i create a new table, but when i try to apply changes to an existing one, created using netbeans palette, it doesnt work. And by the way, even if i use the DefaultTableCellRenderer it should apply both background color and the new font right?

Comment: @Varejator, after creating the UI using a UI builder, you can still do these changes to the generated java code. Yes, I also expected the cell renderer approach also to work. But there's something unexpected going on there.